# How to import a large json file into Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, mongoimport

I have a big json file (~ 300GB) which is composed of many of dicts in it and I am trying to import this file into MongoDB. The method that I tried was mongoimport by using this:
`mongoimport --db <DB_NAME> --collection <COLLECTION_NAME> --file <FILE_DIRECTORY> --jsonArray --batchSize 1`
but it shows the error something like this after some insertions `Failed: error processing document #89602: unexpected EOF`. I have no idea why it happens.

Any other methods to make it work?

Comment: Check the server logs for clues why the server closed the connection.

Comment: You may want to try a _test_ run of the import with a JSON document with a few documents (and with same file). The message is suggesting that the file format has something _unwanted_.